# What to do when you disagree with a non-OP rollback?

Tags: discussion, editing

https://workplace.stackexchange.com/posts/92003/revisions

I had an edit rolled back by someone other than the OP.  Based on the comment that came with it I disagree with the rollback but don't want to get into a rollback war with someone who has exactly as much right to the content of the question as I do.  How are users supposed to handle a situation like this?

Edit
Thanks to Lilienthal for clarifying the process and answering this question.

In this case rather than fight to bring this question on topic, I've asked the generic question as a separate item.  [How to maintain career mobility when in a senior specialist role?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/92040/how-to-maintain-career-mobility-when-in-a-senior-specialist-role)

Comment: Note that the original question has been reopened. There may be significant overlap with your newer question.

Comment: If they are fundamentally different then that is not an issue.  If they are not then the rollback was not justified.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> How are users supposed to handle a situation like this?

In this case, since the roll-back was done by someone who commented on the question, you'd reply to them to try and figure out if there's common ground. Move to a chatroom if it turns into a discussion. If you can't reach consensus you'd typically start a meta thread like you did here.

I guess the issue with the "context" being lost in this particular question is due to the fact that it's also off-topic. OP seems to be asking for career advice and that's difficult to do without details of said career. But questions like those are entirely off-topic here so rather than edit it out a close vote would probably have been more appropriate. There's no point in cleaning up questions that are off-topic at their core no matter how much work is put into them.

Broadly speaking, this level of jargon indeed does *not* belong on this site. If a question doesn't make sense without a dozen [TLAs](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/TLA) and buzz-words then it's not a very good question.

Comment: It's interesting though that while I see it as an edge case in current form.  In the more generic form of "What are strategies for maintaining career mobility when in a senior specialist role?" is much more on topic.

Comment: *If a question doesn't make sense without a dozen TLAs and buzz-words then it's not a very good question.* - Maybe we could put this in the [help] and the new user asking a question popup

Answer (score 3):

Normally, you can edit details out, but in this particular case, you can't. The nature of that question makes those details actually very important. And answering a much more generic version of the question, in my opinion, would be much less valuable to the Original Asker.

And if you think this question doesn't belong on the Workplace, let me suggest that you vote to close the question, or vote to move the question to another Stackexchange.

Sadly, many good questions get closed, or get moved elsewhere, simply because they do not fit the topics of a particular forum, but that's what we ultimately agreed to when joining.

Comment: I feel the question has good merit and in a more generic form is valuable to professionals in other fields who find themselves overspecialized.  This is a major issue in all kinds of technical fields.

Comment: I remember talking to a mechanical engineer last year about how since he has become an expert on pump design other avenues are completely closed to him.

Comment: So when speaking to that expert, he said he was an expert in "pump design", he didn't omit his speciality, and yet you still found what he said useful. In fact, the conversation would have been a lot weirder if he had spoken of his field in super generic terms.

Comment: Also, I believe that "ERP" without any explanation is jargon and it would have been great if he had linked the term to a Wikipedia page explaining the acronym. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_resource_planning But as far as I'm concerned "Java" is not jargon, Java is a programming language. If we have to remove that word from the question, then I suppose you'll want to remove the word "Chinese" from the following question (because I'll bet you do not know Chinese either). https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/79311/how-do-i-indicate-a-localization-project-on-my-resume

Comment: I agree.  These words were not "jargon", these were skill-sets and disciplines, and getting pidgeon-holed in IT is a much more common and greater issue than it is in other disciplines.

Comment: Right but would an answer for a pump design specialist looking for strategies to overcome overspecialization and an Oracle HR ERP specialist looking to overcome overspecialization be fundamentally different?  I would see these as likely duplicates, so the site it better served by having one generic question.

Comment: The details do not matter because what specific skills to learn has been defined as OFF TOPIC.  The generalized question is better because it is more appliciable.

Comment: @Myles the Mech Engineer's problem is that he/she can't communicate. He/she isn't an "expert on pump design," but probably an expert (or at least knowledgeable) about a whole list of topics, which just happen to be *useful* for designing pumps. The *list* is what makes him/her employable, not his current specific *job*.

Comment: @alephzero Do you feel the same way about the HR ERP specialist? The overall point I'm trying to make here is that it doesn't matter which specialization we are talking about, the root problem and the answers all end up being the same.  The current edit of the question keep this tack, my edit was rolled back because I removed details of HR ERP specialization that were apparently integral to the question.